# Passing fk in json via rest call as part of DerivedIdentities

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, dto

I got a Product entity that has an embedded key (id,manufacturer). I'm passing through REST call the product entity with fk of the manufacturer :

```
{
    "name":"Chocolate",
    "register_date":"19/03/2020",
    "manufacturer_id": 52,
    "rating":"Amazing"
}
```

When I try to save the entity in the controller I'm getting the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.dao.Manufacturer field com.dao.ProductId.manufacturer to java.lang.Long
```

Product :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@IdClass(ProductId.class)
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_id_seq", sequenceName = "product_id_seq", initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "product_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Id
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;
    
    private String name;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/YYYY")
    private Date register_date;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Rating rating;

    public enum Rating {
        Amazing,Good_Value_For_Money,Bad
    }
```

The Id class :

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductId implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ProductId pId1 = (ProductId) o;
        if (id != pId1.id) return false;
        return manufacturer.getId() == pId1.manufacturer.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode()+manufacturer.getId().hashCode();
    }
}
```

I also created a DTO object that will be passed through the api to the controller :

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class ProductCreationDTO {


    private String name;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy")
    private Date register_date;
    private Long manufacturer_id;
    private Product.Rating rating;

}
```

The manufacturer :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Manufacturer {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "manufacturer_id_seq", sequenceName = "manufacturer_id_seq", initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "manufacturer_id_seq")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String country;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manufacturer",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Product> products;
```

In my controller I have the following 2 functions :

```
    RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class ProductController {
    
        @Autowired
        ProductService productService;
    
        @Autowired
        ManufacturerService manufacturerService;
    
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/product/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public HttpStatus insertProduct(@RequestBody ProductCreationDTO pcd) {
            Product p = mapProductCreationDTOtoProduct(pcd);
            if(p.getManufacturer() == null)
                return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
            return productService.addProduct(p) ? HttpStatus.CREATED : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        }
    
        private Product mapProductCreationDTOtoProduct(ProductCreationDTO pcd)
        {
            Product p = new Product();
            p.setName(pcd.getName());
            p.setRating(pcd.getRating());
            p.setRegister_date(pcd.getRegister_date());
            Optional<Manufacturer> m = manufacturerService.getManufacturer(pcd.getManufacturer_id());
            if (m.isPresent())
                p.setManufacturer(m.get());
            return p;
        }

the add method under the productService : 

    @Transactional
    public boolean addProduct(Product p)
    {
        return productRepository.save(p)!=null;
    }
```

### Update

I followed the following [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058592/limitation-of-jpa-1-0-using-idclass-with-nested-composite-primary-keys). I changed the ProductId to:

```
public class ProductId implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private Long manufacturer;
....
```

and in the Product class I added the following annotation above the Manufacturer :

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId("manufacturer")
private Manufacturer manufacturer;
```

and now I'm getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No part of a composite identifier may be null
```

### Update 2

It looks like the id of the Product isn't populated and that's why it isn't created. I tried setting the id in the following function and the product was inserted successfully:

```
private Product mapProductCreationDTOtoProduct(ProductCreationDTO pcd)
{
    Product p = new Product();
    p.setName(pcd.getName());
    p.setRating(pcd.getRating());
    p.setRegister_date(pcd.getRegister_date());
    Optional<Manufacturer> m = manufacturerService.getManufacturer(pcd.getManufacturer());
    if (m.isPresent())
        p.setManufacturer(m.get());
    p.setId((long) 1);   <-------------------------------------------
    return p;
}
```

So the open question now is why the id isn't populated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original problem was :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.dao.Manufacturer field com.dao.ProductId.manufacturer to java.lang.Long
```

I solved it by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058592/limitation-of-jpa-1-0-using-idclass-with-nested-composite-primary-keys) . The bottom line was that inside my IdClass, the type of the composite object should be his PK :

```
public class ProductId implements Serializable {

    private Long id; // matches name of @Id attribute
    private Long manufacturer; // name should match to @Id attribute and type of Manufacturer PK
```

Althought after solving it I faced a new :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No part of a composite identifier may be null
```

might be a [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10956)(or this [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6044)) related to hibernate when using @Idclass.

Either way, the way to handle this problem and solve it is initiate the id column to a value :

```
public class Product {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_id_seq", sequenceName = "product_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "product_id_seq")
    private Long id=-1L;
```

This will bypass hibernate validation of the id and allow it to map the sequence value to it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious mistake is a `@id` annotation over the `name` property in the `Product` entity whereas it should be over the `manufacturer` property

Comment: You are right, indeed the @id should have been above the manufacturer property. I changed that but I'm getting the same error. Not sure that it is related..

Comment: does an `id` property in the `Manufacturer` entity annotate with `@Id`?

Comment: I fixed the original issue but another one appeared because of my solution, left an update on the main post

Comment: Left another update ,it seems like the id of the product that I create in the controller isnt initialized and thats why the exception is raised.